# Get page using NTLM with pyCurl

Tags: python, rest, curl, pycurl

I am trying to retrieve data from a REST webservice which is hosted on a Windows IIS server; the server uses HTTPS and requires authentication.

The following Curl command works fine:

```
 curl -k --ntlm --user bob https://mywebservice
```

However when I come to translate this to the equivalent pycurl so I can use it from within a program I am struggling to get it to authenticate.

So far I have:

```
import pycurl

name='bob'
pwd='pwd1'
url="https://mywebservice"

curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)

#not sure about this
#curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXYAUTH, pycurl.HTTPAUTH_NTLM)
#curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXYUSERPWD,"{}:{}".format(name, pwd))

curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPAUTH, pycurl.HTTPAUTH_NTLM)
curl.setopt(pycurl.USERNAME, name)
curl.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, pwd)


curl.perform()
curl.close()
```

Anyway, with the following code and variations on it, I keep getting:

```
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials
```

back from IIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was that I was using `pycurl.USERNAME`, `pycurl.USERPWD`.

I had to route through the source but I found: pycurl.USERPWD and that got it working:

```
import pycurl

name='bob'
pwd='pwd1'
url="https://mywebservice"

curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
curl.setopt(pycurl.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)

curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPAUTH, pycurl.HTTPAUTH_NTLM)
curl.setopt(pycurl.USERPWD, "{}:{}".format(name, pwd))

curl.perform()
curl.close()
```